# How to get to a child of a parent when multiple exist?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is problem with the following code. I am trying to Increase the dollar amount for all the numbers independently (by 0.01 per click). But it only seems to work on the first "content" class, not on the other 2. Each of these are identical besides the amount.

Layout:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="item"><span class="number">$10.11</span><a href="#" class="incNumber"> Increase</a></div>
</div>
<div class="content">
   <div class="item"><span class="number">$5.04</span><a href="#" class="incNumber"> Increase</a></div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="item"><span class="number">$3.45</span><a href="#" class="incNumber"> Increase</a></div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$(function () {
   $(".incNumber").click(function() {
      brother = $(this).closest('div').children('.number');
      amount = $(brother).html().replace(/[^\d\.]/g, "");
      amount = parseFloat(amount);

      $(brother).html('$'+String(amount.toFixed(2)));
      return false;
   });
});
```

This script seems to function fine. converting it to a float and then back seems to increase it by 0.01 however this is not intentional...

Comment: Mmh, your script does nothing in my case (values are not increased). But if I add the addition, it works for every number. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/RtLfc/

Comment: not an answer: `brother` is already a jQuery object. no need to wrap it like `$(brother)`. Just `brother`, like `brother.html()` will do. ;)

Comment: Ok I have played around removing other scripts.
It seems that Cufon is to blame. I use the following to replace fonts in my site.
Cufon.replace(parent, { fontFamily: 'Rockwell Extra Bold', hover:true, textShadow: '#00b1fd 0px 1px, #073e74 0px -1px' });

Comment: I guess I cant convert a custom font to a float then back.

Comment: Possibly independent of your problem: I'd avoid calculating with floats, and use integers and calcuate with cents instead. Floats always have the danger of introducing rounding errors.

Comment: RoToRa: You suggest using parseInt(int*100) +1; and then converting back?

Also for those who may be looking for a solution to something similar while using cufon.
I have replaced cufon with font squirrel, this does not use JS to create the font but rather embeds the font file itself into your webpage. You dont get all teh fancy effects but its stable. http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, your code works without any unexpected behavior... it does nothing. But when I change this

```
amount = parseFloat(amount) + 0.01;
```

The increase button increases the individual numbers by 0.01

Comment: Hmm. there must be more to this than i thought. I will investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

From the jQuery documentation you can find this:

> In an HTML document, we can use
>   .html() to get the contents of any
>   element. If the selector expression
>   matches more than one element, **only
>   the first one's HTML** content is
>   returned.

http://api.jquery.com/html/

You might use each to iterate over all elements found...

Comment: I think this is not the problem, `$(this).closest('div').children('.number')` will return one only element anyway (meaning there is only one element in the selection).

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed  the incrementing. but anyways this is a modified version of ur code. I hope I got what you are trying to do.

```
$(function () {
    $(".incNumber").click(function() {
    brother = $(this).siblings('.number');
    amount = $(brother).html().replace(/[^\d\.]/g, "");
    amount = parseFloat(amount);
    amount = amount + 0.01;
    $(brother).html('$'+String(amount.toFixed(2)));
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, for some reason because I was converting the font with coufon,  I didn't need the increment, coufon seemed to have caused strange rounding errors. Once I removed coufon and used a websafe font, the increment worked as intended.